# Functional Requirement vs Non-Functional Requirement for Uber Application

Tags: uber-api, requirements, system-requirements

What is the difference between the functional requirement and non-functional requirement for Uber application?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2):

**Regardless UberApi (or any product or technology)**

The terms are **general terms**.

If you have a client that asks you to develop an **e-commerce web site** that will be reached by customers thousands of times every minute, then based on this example:

**Functional** Requirements are:

1. Customer should be able to list products
2. Customer should be able to place order
3. Customer should be able to pay by card

and so on

**Non-functional** Requirements (Technical Requirement)

1. The Site should be able to serve a huge number of customers at the
   same time without problems.
2. The site should be secure enough because there will be sensitive data.

and so on

So you can consider **functional** as the Domain(Business) requirements while the **non-functional** as the supportive requirements.